# W3i offerwall sdk

Tags: java, android

i have a question, i am trying to add to my app the w3i offerwall, for monetization...
Here are the sdk guide: https://associate.w3i.com/integration/index.html
I have added the offerwall easily, but now i have to immagazinate in a variable what the user have earned...
The guide tell:

Redeeming Currencies
Currency redemption should occur when the application opens, each time it starts. 
If you are showing the offer alert dialog, we recommend that you call redeemCurrency() first and follow it immediately with showFeaturedOffer().  This creates a logical flow for the user who is rewarded with currency from the last offer they completed before being prompted with the offer alert. 
The method which handles redeeming currencies is redeemCurrency(), and it has the following signature:

```
public void redeemCurrency(final Activity context, W3iCurrencyListener listener )
```

This method requires the current Activity context, not an Application context, as it shows the user a message dialog when currencies have been redeemed.  In addition, you need to provide an implementation of the W3iCurrencyListener interface. 
Next, your application needs to provide an implementation of the W3iCurrencyListener interface.  The W3iCurrencyListener interface is used to notify the game that currencies were returned.  Balances are returned as a List collection.  An example implementation follows:

```
W3iCurrencyListener callback = new W3iCurrencyListener() {
              @Override
              onRedeem(List<Balance> balances) {

                     //Take possession of the balances returned here.             

              }
};
```

The collection of Balance objects may be for different currency types, if your application supports multiple currencies. 
If the call to redeemCurrency() succeeds, you will receive a collection of balances.  If not, the onRedeem() callback will not fire.  This method will not return currencies unless a user has converted an offer by downloading and installing an application, or completing another action for non-app offers.

Now i don't know how to use this code, how can i set the return to a variable? Now i hope that theire office are closed, so i ask that to you...
Thakns, matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced a similar issue. I implemented their com.w3i.offerwall.W3iCurrencyListener and used it to call redeemCurrency().

I am calling redeemCurrency() in the launcher activity. My W3IListener overrides onRedeem() method. Hope the following code snippet will clear your doubts.

```
 public class MyGame extends Acitvity{
     private W3iCurrencyListener w3iListener = new W3iListener(this);
     public static int coins = 0;
     @Override
     protected void onResume(){
         try{
             w3iInstance.redeemCurrency(this, w3iListener);
         }
         catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }


public class W3iListener implements com.w3i.offerwall.W3iCurrencyListener{

    private Context mContext = null;

    public W3iListener(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }   


    @Override
    public void onRedeem(List<Balance> paramList) {
            if(paramList.size()>0)
            {
                int coins = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<paramList.size(); i++){
                    coins += Integer.parseInt(paramList.get(i).getAmount());
                }
                MyGame.coins = coins + MyGame.coins;
            }
    }
}
```